# Given C is a code of length n. Containing M code-words with a distance d

Tags: encryption

I'm studying for my exam and came across this question below.
I don't understand how to get $d$. I get $C$ is a code of length $n$.
Containing $M$ code-words with a distance $d$.

$(n,M,d)$

But how do I get $d$ below?

> Give one (5,4,d) code in … as below …
>       Z^(5) base 2.
>
> C={
>   0,0,0,1,0
>   0,1,1,0,1
>   1,0,1,1,0
>   1,1,0,1,1
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *distance* of the code word is the minimum number of bit flips that transforms one codeword into another. It's just the minimum of all possible hamming distances between the codes.

Also you can define the *weight* of a codeword to be the distance from the zero vector.

For your code it looks like $d = 2$.

Comment: Thanks once you said hamming distance the penny dropped.